# linked static libraries C

Tags: c, libraries

I have made my own sample library and I want to use it in my main file. All my code is:

Sum.h:

```
#ifndef _SUM_H_
#define _SUM_H_

int add(int n1, int n2);

#endif
```

Sum.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "sum.h"

int add(int n1, int n2)
{
     return n1 + n2;
}
```

main.c:

```
#include "sum.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    printf("%d", add(1, 2));    

    return 0;
}
```

For using the library, I have written these commands:

> gcc -c -o sum.o sum.c
>
> ar rcs libsum.a sum.o
>
> gcc main.c

My problem is that the last command, which compiles the main file, returns me that error:

```
main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:5:2: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘printf’ [enabled by default]
  printf("%d", suma(1, 2)); 
  ^
/tmp/ccyhA7Bc.o: In `main' function:
main.c:(.text+0x1a): reference to `sum' undefined 
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

All files are in the same directory. Where is my mistake? How can I fixed it?

Comment: Is the error message you include representative of the exact source code you are showing?  I do not see a _printf("%d", suma(1, 2));_ in your source, but the error message appears to include that statement.

Comment: @ryyker: It looks like the OP translated the code from Spanish to English for asking the question, but he forgot to redo the error messages.

Comment: Indeed ... leads to a piece of advise: *always* do all your coding in english. It's MUCH easier to share later (and maybe find team members, contributors, ...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to link in the library, it is not looked for automatically:

```
gcc main.c libsum.a
```

Or if you prefer:

```
gcc main.c -L. -lsum
```

These options are:

- `-L.` adds the current directory to the library path. Normally only the system and compiler library directories are included.
- `-lsum` looks for `libsum.a` (or `libsum.so`, the dynamic library variant) in the library path.

Note that a library with just one object file is not very useful: you can just link with:

```
gcc main.c sum.o
```

About the warning, you have to `#include <stdio.h>` in every compilation unit that uses `printf()`. You have it in `sum.c`, but that does not make the declarations available to `main.c`. If you added it to `sum.h` then it would have been included (not that it is a good idea to add random `include`s to your header files).

Comment: nice to see the (in practice more common) syntax with a library search path, but ... care to explain it, too, to make this a great answer? :)

Comment: Also, you're right about inclusion in `sum.h`, but as this seems to be a beginner's question, a little more elaboration on this (explicitly include where needed, plan for changes!) would probably be nice :) Still very good answer!

Comment: @FelixPalmen: Ok, some explanation added. About inclusion, I'm not sure about what the OP is doing with `<stdio.h>`, but just adding it where the compiler complains is usually is enough, I don't know what else to add.

Comment: yes thanks, showed my appreciation ;) And of course, that's a basic strategy, but following it, it would be "wrong" in `sum.c`. What I meant is you also don't want to rely on `stdio.h` being included in `sum.h` either, because `sum.h` could be changed ... so explicitly add includes exactly where they're really used.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
gcc main.c -L. -lsum
```

The `-L` for the directory and the `-lsum` for the name of the library

The other error is because you didn't include `<stdio.h>` for your `main`.

Answer (score 1):

There's more than one error. Let's first focus on the warning here:

> main.c:5:2: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘printf’ [enabled by default]

You forgot to `#include <stdio.h>`. `printf()` is declared there. It's not strictly necessary in C to have a declaration of a function before calling it, if you don't have one, it's assumed to take any number of arguments and return `int`. But this is just legacy. Always make sure to actually **have** a declaration -- for library functions, include the appropriate header.

Then to the linker error: That's easily explained:

> gcc main.c

This command tries to compile just `main.c` to an executable. This can't work because in `main.c`, you call a function that is defined in another module and that isn't *magically* available to the compiler. In your case, just add your library to the commandline:

> gcc main.c libsum.a

I didn't try it right now, but it should work.